# Alternative for glBlitFrameBuffer() in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

My Android program must use `glBlitFrameBuffer()` function to copy `FrameBuffer` object. But `glBlitFrameBuffer()` function is only supported on OpenGL ES 3.0+ devices. I want to support OpenGL ES 2.0+ devices.

Is there any solution/alternative for this function?

Answer (score 2):

1. Bind texture that used  as collor attachment on source frame buffer
2. Bind destination framebuffer
3. Draw full screen quad (if you need stretch or offseted reading manipulate with vertex/tex coordinates)
4. Fetch data from bound texture in frament shader and put it to gl_FragColor

Answer (score 0):

I've created a CopyShader that simply uses a shader to copy from a texture to a framebuffer.

```
private static final String SHADER_VERTEX = ""
      + "attribute vec4 a_Position;\n"
      + "varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;\n"
      + "void main() {\n"
      + "  v_TexCoordinate = a_Position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;\n"
      + "  gl_Position = a_Position;\n"
      + "}\n";

  private static final String SHADER_FRAGMENT = ""
      + ""
      + "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;\n"
      + "varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;\n"
      + "void main() {\n"
      + "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);\n"
      + "}\n”;
```

Use these as your shaders, and then just set `u_Texture` to the texture you want to copy **from**, and bind the framebuffer you want to write to, and you should be set.